# Get the DISTINCT id of users and find the MAX of their column then UPDATE, LARAVEL

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder

What I want to do is, the `distinct` `id` based on the `max` value of the associated column and then `update` a column accordingly.

For example

```
id  |  name  |  total  |  description  |  updateThis

1   |  john  |  100    |  example      |      0
2   |  dave  |  300    |  example      |      0  
2   |  johno |  500    |  example      |      0
4   |  derik |  900    |  example      |      0
5   |  Sam   |  1000   |  example      |      0
4   |  bool  |  12200  |  example      |      0
1   |  john  |  1200   |  example      |      0
5   |  john  |  300    |  example      |      0
```

I want it to look like this:

```
id  |  name  |  total  |  description  |  updateThis

1   |  john  |  1200   |  example      |      1
2   |  johno |  500    |  example      |      1
4   |  bool  |  12200  |  example      |      1
5   |  Sam   |  1000   |  example      |      1
```

I am using Query Builder not the eloquent way of doing it, either would be a useful answer and if someone can give both that would be awesome too, I just need help thanks.

Comment: Should the other rows stay as they are?

Comment: Yes only the ones that I wanted is to be updated/changed.

Comment: Do you want to update the rows directly in the database with a single query? Or retrieve them first and then update them?

Comment: In a sense, retrieve them then update? I think? So I am doing this logic in the Laravel Controller and I get the rows I want then update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```php
$rows = DB::table('table')
    ->select('id', DB::raw('max(total) as total'))
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->get();
foreach($rows as $row) {
    DB::table('table')
        ->where('id', $row->id)
        ->where('total', $row->total)
        ->update(['updateThis' => 1]);
}
```